# Is there a way to specify the branch Tree while using github as the backend for netlify CMS?

Tags: github-api, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm using netlifyCMS and I've just added github authentication which works alright. The issue is when I try accessing my collection, all of them are empty and the reason is the github API request being made to read the content is wrong.
Here is the `GET` request being made
`https://api.github.com/repos/CodeForAfrica/ui/git/trees/main:content/donors`
However, since I'm in a monorepo the path should be `..trees/main:apps/codeforafrica/content/donors`

The only location I see the branch being set is in the config file

```
backend: {
    name: "github",
    branch: "main",
    repo: "CodeForAfrica/ui",
    proxy_url: "http://localhost:8081/api/v1", // Set proxy to work on local repo
  },
```

If I try doing

```
backend: {
    name: "github",
    branch: "main:apps/codeforafrica",
    repo: "CodeForAfrica/ui",
    proxy_url: "http://localhost:8081/api/v1", // Set proxy to work on local repo
  },
```

The request is now

```
https://api.github.com/repos/CodeForAfrica/ui/git/trees/main:apps/codeforafrica:content/donors
```

Which is wrong.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to set this; instead, you solve this by setting the correct `file` or `folder` location.
In my case, I only had to set `file: "apps/codeforafrica/content/pages/index.md"` instead of `file: "content/pages/index.md"`